# Null reference exception

Tags: asp.net

I have a function like this

```
public bool CheckMentorAccess()
{
    bool blnAllow = false;
    try
    {
        string strSelectMentorQuery = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT MLL.LED_ID) FROM M_USER_DETAILS MUD INNER JOIN M_LEADERLED MLL " + "ON MLL.LED_ID = MUD.PK_ID WHERE MLL.LEADER_ID = '" + Session["UserID"].ToString() + "' AND MUD.ACTIVE = 1 AND MLL.START_DATE <= Getdate() AND" + " MLL.END_DATE > Getdate()";

        int intNoOfMembers = Convert.ToInt32(cSQLHelper.myExecuteScalar(strSelectMentorQuery));

        if (intNoOfMembers > 0)
        {
            blnAllow = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ExceptionLogger.LogException(ex);
        blnAllow = false;
    }

    // Return the value
    return blnAllow;
}
```

And then I use if like this

```
if ((Int32.Parse(Session["ROLE_ID"].ToString()) == 3) && (CheckMentorAccess() == true))
{
    cmbempList.Visible = true;
}
```

but it is throwing a null reference exception on the first line of the sample above

Can anyone help me out..

Comment: Does the key "ROLE_ID" actually exist in Session?

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
if (Session["ROLE_ID"] != null && (Int32.Parse(Session["ROLE_ID"].ToString()) == 3) && (CheckMentorAccess() == true))
{
    cmbempList.Visible = true;
}
```

First check that `Session["ROLE_ID"]` exists before you use ToString.

It is always safer to use [Convert.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tostring%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the stack trace *only* points at that line, I'd guess this is the problem:

```
Int32.Parse(Session["ROLE_ID"].ToString())
```

That will throw a `NullReferenceException` if `Session["ROLE_ID"]` returns null.

(It will throw `FormatException` if the value exists in the session but isn't a valid integer.)

It's possible that it's the call to `CheckMentor()` which is failing, of course - but then your stack trace should say so. That could fail if `cSQLHelper` is null, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - check the values you are using when you call the method:

```
if (Session["ROLE_ID"] != null)
{
    if ((Int32.Parse(Session["ROLE_ID"]) == 3) && (CheckMentorAccess())) 
    { 
        cmbempList.Visible = true; 
    } 
}
```

and check in the method

```
public bool CheckMentorAccess()
{
    if (Session["UserID"] == null)
    {
        throw new NullReferenceException("UserID is null");
    }

    bool blnAllow = false;
    try
    {
        string strSelectMentorQuery = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT MLL.LED_ID) FROM M_USER_DETAILS MUD INNER JOIN M_LEADERLED MLL " + "ON MLL.LED_ID = MUD.PK_ID WHERE MLL.LEADER_ID = '" + Session["UserID"].ToString() + "' AND MUD.ACTIVE = 1 AND MLL.START_DATE <= Getdate() AND" + " MLL.END_DATE > Getdate()";

        int intNoOfMembers = Convert.ToInt32(cSQLHelper.myExecuteScalar(strSelectMentorQuery));

        blnAllow = intNoOfMembers > 0;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ExceptionLogger.LogException(ex);
        blnAllow = false;
    }

    // Return the value
    return blnAllow;
}
```